# How to define allowed_address_pairs for openstack instance's port in Cloudify blueprint?

Tags: openstack, cloudify

I am trying to write a Cloudify blueprint for a basic network topology that contains a firewall instance (just be iptables) that is responsible for filtering traffic (I integrated Cloudify with OpenStack for application orchestration).

However, I realised that OpenStack does not allow an instance to route traffic because of port_security. I solved this problem manually by disabling `port_security` or adding specific source IP addresses (hosts or subnets) to firewall's port using an option called `allowed_address_pairs`.

Now I want to know how this can be solved automatically by defining one of above options in Cloudify blueprint?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem after reading carefully documents about OpenStack API and OpenStack plugin's Cloudify.